# Redirect to Html.ActionLink when click div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, razor

i want to do clickable div and when clicked redirect to Html.ActionLink lockated inside said div.

this is the clickable div jquery

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(".linkdiv").click(function () {
        if ($(this).find("a").length) {
            window.location.href = $(this).find(".top-menu-link").attr("href");
        }
    });
</script>
```

and this is how i have written the div:

```
<div id="top-menu-element" class="linkdiv">
     @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { @class = "top-menu-link" })
</div>
```

i think that the .attr("href") should be something diffrent but i didn't manage to find out what it should be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(".linkdiv").click(function () {
        var anchor = $(this).find("a");
        if (anchor.length) {
            anchor.trigger("click"); 
        }
    });
</script>
```

Just call the click event for the anchor and use the normal flow of the anchor tag.
If this doesn't work try to put this bind click event to the anchor:

```
$(".linkdiv").find("a").click( function (e) {
  window.location.href = this.href;
});
```

Or more simple replace:

```
anchor.trigger("click");
```

With:

```
anchor.get(0).click();
```

Comment: ok so in find("a") instead of a i give it to find .top-menu-link and then i do anchor.click() - that should immitate behaviour of clicking url shouldn't it ?

Comment: @JakubWisniewski exactly, your trigger the normal behavior of the anchor.

Comment: well but somehow it's not working and i am not quite sure why (still i am newbie in using jquery)

Comment: i had to tweak few things but i got this to work :) thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If the script is in the Razor view, just use:

```
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';
```

Which `Url.Action` does the same thing.

Comment: the problem is that is not reusable - i have more links and with this approach i have to write much more code for them